# How to make this JavaScript code more practical?

Tags: javascript, background, setinterval, performance

I created code as practice.This changes the background color of the browser based on what you type into the text box.  I couldn't figure how to do it any other way than using the setInterval() method but it annoys me.  I feel like there must be a better way of doing it in which it doesn't involve checking for changes every ten milliseconds. Any solutions?

```
setInterval(function(){colorNow()},10);
function colorNow(){
    var chooseColor = document.getElementById("color").value;;
    document.bgColor = chooseColor;
}
```

Comment: Events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: More about events: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Comment: Specifically this event (IMOHO): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onkeyup

Comment: Specifically, see the `keyup` event to run something whenever the user types.

Comment: @Doorknob Why did you remove the HTML from the question?

Comment: @Barmar Because it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `keyup` event:

```
document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('keyup', colorNow)
```

This will call `colorNow` every time the user releases a key (when a letter gets typed).

Comment: I'm just learning to code from a book so I've never seen events before :P.  So from what I understand from looking at this this thing called and "event" will happen when you lift your key, and calls on colorNow().  Is that right? Thanks for your quick answer!

Comment: @Zachooz: Then you should definitely read http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html, it's a really good and comprehensive introduction to events.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this use a `keyup` event

```
var chooseColor = document.getElementById("color");
chooseColor.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    document.bgColor = chooseColor.value;
}, false);
```

So a little bit on events here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

> The `keyup` event - basically the function provided to the `keyup` event will be called every time the user releases a key **while** the input is `focused` that's because we added the `event` directly to the`chooseColor` element
>
> The `false` section of the function is `default` (it's called */bubbling|bubble|bubbles/* ) and it stops the event bubbling up the DOM Tree, so if it were `true` the parent(s) of that element will be notified of the event.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.bubbles
>
> ## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g6UTE/2)

Comment: I understand most of it but what does the , false do? Thanks for the answer btw :).

Comment: Edit it, Ummm what does that mean?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeColor() {
    document.bgColor = this.value;
}

document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("change", changeColor);
document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("keyup", changeColor);
```

Comment: Correct answer but why would you select the element **twice** ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the onchange event with your input tag to call your colorNow() function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Obligatory link: http://www.w3fools.com/. This can been as nitpick, but the event is called *change event*, not *onchange event*. `onchange` is just the name of the attribute/property because the assigned function is executed *on change*.

Comment: The man in your profile picture looks like he has just been to http://w3schools.com